# findAll is not a function ; sequelize en electron

Tags: nodejs, electron, sequelize

Estoy en proceso de aprendizaje de nodejs, electron y como aplicación de ejemplo estoy realizando el almacenaje de doctores y otras tablas, para mostrarles el error que tengo y no puedo solucionar utilizare el código pertinente a esta tabla doctor.
Estuve picando código de un lado y de otro intentando solucionar este problemas así que tal vez el código les resulte desordenado perdón por eso y cualquier duda intentare aclararla.

este es mi archivo index.js que arranca toda la aplicación.

```
const db = require("./db/database.js");
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");
const templatemenu = require("./views/menu.js");
let mainWindow;
prueba();
function prueba() {
    db()
        .models.doctor.findAll()
        .then((doctores) => {
            doctores.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.apellidos);
            });
        });
}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require("electron-reload")(__dirname, {
        electron: path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules", ".bin", "electron"),
    });
}

app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
        },
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, "views/index.html"),
            protocol: "file",
            slashes: true,
        })
    );
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(templatemenu.templatemenu);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
    mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
        app.quit();
    });
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    templatemenu.pusher();
}
```

aquí al ejecutar la función prueba, todo funciona correctamente y en consola muestra todos los apellidos doctores registrados en la base de datos. Pero ahora, hice un menú de navegación que abre ventanas internas que no es nada del otro mundo, mediante este código para que no haya ninguna duda.

```
function operadordeventana(pagina, dimension) {
    let direccion = "../views/" + pagina + ".html";
    ventanainterna = new BrowserWindow(dimension);
    //ventanainterna.setMenu(null);
    ventanainterna.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, direccion),
            protocol: "file",
            slashes: true,
        })
    );
}
```

bueno, aqui es donde tengo el problema, al abrir la ventana designada a los doctores coloque este código, que al hacer submit en un formulario ejecuta básicamente el mismo codigo de la funcion prueba() del archivo index.js pero me lanza este

```
error Uncaught TypeError: doctor.findAll is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (doctor.js:12)
(anonymous) @ doctor.js:12
```

este es el código del archivo doctor.js

```
const formulariodoctor = document.getElementById("doctor");
const { remote } = require("electron");
const principal = remote.require("./db/database.js");
const doctor = remote.require("./db/models/tabla_doctor.js");
formulariodoctor.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    principal();

    //console.log(principal().models.paciente);

    //principal()
    //    .models.doctor.findAll()
    //    .then((doctores) => {
    //        doctores.forEach((doc) => {
    //            console.log(doc.apellidos);
    //        });
    //    });
    doctor.findAll().then((doctores) => {
        doctores.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.apellidos);
        });
    });
});
```

Como explique a un principio la función findAll() en el archivo de la ventana padre index.js no tiene ningún problema en ejecutar la función, en la ventana hija doctor me lanza el problema de que findAll() no es una función, soy nuevo en esta tecnología de nodejs y es probable que sea algún descuido mio, por favor quedare muy agradecido con su ayuda.